# Средства выражения категории рода у несклоняемых имён существительных

Tags: морфология

Скажите, пожалуйста, в словосочетании *симпатичный шимпанзе* формальное отнесение к мужскому роду по категории одушевленности у несклоняемых и. с. будет являться морфологическим средством выражения категории рода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, это синтаксическое средство: у несклоняемых существительных **форма согласуемого слова в словосочетании** является единственным средством выражения рода:

• симпатичный шимпанзе

> Род в современном русском языке может выражаться с помощью средств
>   различных уровней.
>
> 1. Морфологические средства - характер основы и окончание в именительном падеже единственного числа. Каждому роду свойственна своя
>      система окончаний.
> 2. Словообразовательные средства:
>
> • учительØ — учительница
>
> • студентØ — студентка
>
> -знь- жизнь (ж. р.)   боязнь (ж. р.)
>
> -ость-    смелость (ж. р.)    храбрость (ж. р.)
>
> -изм- героизм (м. р.) патриотизм (м. р.)
>
> -ениj-    воображени[j]е (ср. р.) терпени[j]е (ср. р.)
>
> 3. Лексико-семантические средства:
>
> • мать — отец •   брат — сестра
>
> • мужчина — женщина
>
> • конь — лошадь
>
> • баран — овца
>
> • муж — жена
>
> 4. Синтаксические средства: — формы согласования или координации:
>
> • просторная комната
>
> • просторный коридорØ
>
> • просторное помещение
>
> • мой товарищØ
>
> • мое пальто
>
> • моя жизньØ (шляпа)
>
> — c краткими прилагательными:
>
> • ночь нежна
>
> • сестра весела
>
> • небо сине
>
> — с формами полных и кратких причастий:
>
> • отправленная телеграмма
>
> • задача решена
>
> • выходØ найденØ
>
> — с формами глаголов прошедшего времени единственного числа:
>
> • закончился дождьØ
>
> • закончилось затмение
>
> • закончилась гроза
>
> — с глаголами в форме сослагательного наклонения:
>
> • Поскорее б пришло лето.
>
> • Поскорее пришла бы весна.
>
> У несклоняемых существительных форма согласуемого слова является
>   единственным средством выражения рода:
>
> • кофе молотый
>
> • пальто осеннее
>
> • кенгуру прыгалØ

https://goldrussian.ru/sredstva-vyrazhenija-roda.html